# Slow down a `split`

Tags: find, xargs, split

I have a really large archive consisting of really small files, concatenated into a
single text file, with a "" dilimiter.  For smaller archives, I would `split`
the archive using "" as a pattern, and then work on the resulting files.
However, in this archive there are on the order of magnitude of a hundred million
such files -- clearly, too much for putting them all into a single directory.  I
have created folders `aa`, `ab`, etc. for trying to move them into directories as
they are created.  However, I ran into issues.  Things I've tried:

1. There is no command for `split` to execute any command on the resulting file.  So
   I have to do it by hand.
2. Moving the files into the `**` directory using `find . -name "xaa*" -exec mv {} aa \+` does not work because `{}` is not at the end of the line.
3. The `-t` flag, for reversing the source and the destination, is not available in
   my version of Unix.
4. I had to pipe the output of `find` into `xargs`, for it to work out.

However, this is too slow -- files are being created way faster than they are moved
away.

5. I suspect that `xargs` is processing less files at a time than using a `\+` after
   `find -exec`.  I tried adding a `-R 6000' flag, for running 6000 entries at a time;
   however, I don't think it made a difference.
6. I decreased the priority of `split` to the lowest possible.  No change in the
   amount of CPU it consumed, so probably no effect either.
7. I open up to seven command prompts for running the `mv` commands (last four
   letters per command prompt) -- however, this is still not nearly enough.  I would
   open more, but once the system gets to seven, the response is so slow that I have to
   stop the split.  For example, the source archive got copied to a USB all while
   waiting for a `ls -l | tail` command to return something.

So what I've been doing is, stopping the `split` at that point, waiting for the `mv`
commands to catch up, and then restarting the split.  At that point I would use
`find -exec rm {} \+` to delete the files I already have; this is a bit faster, so
when it gets to the files I don't have, there's less files around.

So the first such iteration lasted ~3 million files, the next one ~2 million, the
next ~1.5.  I am sure there should be a better way, though.  Any ideas for what else
to try?

Comment: So if your `mv` doesn't support `-t`, how is using `xargs` going to help? Something like `xargs -I {} ... mv {} aa` is still going to run `mv` once per each line of input. You'd need something like `xargs sh -c 'mv "$@" aa' _` (or at that point, just `find ... -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" aa' _ {} +`) to really run a single `mv` for multiple files. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: I see.  So that is why it is so slow -- wasn't aware of that.  Yes, that's what I'm doing.  If you post this for an answer (explaining the $@) then I can accept it.

Comment: "There is no command for `split` to execute any command on the resulting file" – There is in GNU `split`: `--filter`. I understand your `split` does not support it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for pointing it out, possibly downloading the GNU `split` would make my job easier; I can look into it.

Comment: It worked!  The total went up to 11 million files after the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `xargs -I {} ... mv {} aa` is still going to run `mv` once per each line of input. From [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) of the `-I` option of `xargs`:

```
Insert mode: utility is executed for each  logical  line  from  standard  input.
```

You'd need something like `xargs -r sh -c 'mv "$@" aa' _` (or at that point, just `find ... -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" aa' _ {} +`) to really run a single `mv` for multiple files. With this, you're using the shell to insert the arguments between `mv` and the target directory.

- `"$@"` is substituted by the shell with all arguments without any field splitting or globbing.
- The `_` is acting as `$0` for the script specified to `sh -c`. The arguments after that will be `$1`, `$2`, etc., or collectively, `$@`.

Even with this, I think your `find` will be involved in race conditions. It might end up finishing reading the directory list before `split` ends, and so may not process all files. It might also end up recursing into the subdirectories you've made and detect the files that were previously moved there, and may end up trying to move `aa/xaa` to `aa/` again and erroring out (however, `-exec ... {} +` ignores the command's exit status).

Comment: +1 for the comments at the bottom.  In particular, the workaround for recursing into subdirectories is to put the `aa` directories one level higher.  Otherwise, even if you specify a max depth `-d 1`, `find` still recurses through all subdirectories (ignoring the files there), and taking longer than the `split`.